# Unknown host 'android-sdk.is.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, build.gradle

Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

[image]